# Is there a way to avoid double quotation in formatting strings which include quotations inside them in Python

Tags: python, string, string.format, quotation-marks

It is not supposed to be a hard problem, but I've worked on it for almost a day!

I want to create a query which has to be in this format: 'lat':'###','long':'###' where ###s represent latitude and longitude.

I am using the following code to generate the queries:

```
coordinateslist=[]
for i in range(len(lat)):
     coordinateslist.append("'lat':'{}','long':'-{}'".format(lat[i],lon[i]))
coordinateslist
```

However the result would be some thing similar to this which has "" at the beginning and end of it: "'lat':'40.66','long':'-73.93'"

Ridiculously enough it's impossible to remove the " with either .replace or .strip! and wrapping the terms around `repr` doesn't solve the issue.
Do you know how I can get rid of those double quotation marks?

P.S. I know that when I print the command the `"`will not be shown but when i use each element of the array in my query, a `"` will appear at the end of the query which stops it from working.
directly writing the line like this:

```
query_params = {'lat':'43.57','long':'-116.56'}
```

works perfectly fine.

but using either of the codes below will lead to an error.

```
aa=print(coordinateslist[0])
bb=coordinateslist[0]

query_params = {aa}
query_params = {bb}
query_params = aa
query_params = bb
```

Comment: Those quotes are not actually there, they are the representation of the string. If you try to print the string to the screen (e.g., `print(coordinateslist[0])`), you will notice that there are no `" "` around the string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when I use the code you mentioned in my query i get the error 'message': 'Invalid coordinates.'
and when i directly use coordinateslist[0] in the query, i see " appearing in the query like this: reverse_geocode.json?'lat':'41.83','long':'-87.68'",

Comment: Again, those `"` are just to tell you "this object is a string". They are not actually there. When you access strings directly, Python will put the `"` around them to inform you that the type of this object is a string. When your code accesses the object, the `"` is not there. Again, for example, try to `print(coordinateslist[0])`. You will see that there are no `"` in the output.

Comment: Please see the p.s of the post i just added.

Comment: Maybe you meant to do `coordinateslist.append({"lat": lat[i], "long": "-{}".format(lon[i])})`?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be making a list of strings. Make a list of dictionaries and convert it to JSON.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, i had not thought about that.

Comment: @sepehr No problem, I added my answer onto this post. If I helped, please upvote it and mark it as valid using the checkmark :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a dictionary instead, if you don't want to see the `"` from string representation:

```py
coordinateslist.append({
    "lat": lat[i],
    "long": "-{}".format(lon[i])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the error you are getting is something else entirely (i.e. unrelated to the quotes you are seeing in printed outputs).  From the format of the query, I would guess that it is expecting a properly formatted URL parameters: `reverse_geocode.json?...` which `'lat':'41.83','long':'-87.68'` is not.   Did you try to manually call it with a fixed string, (e.g. using with postman) ?

Assuming you're calling the twitter geo/ API, you might want to ry it out with properly separated URL parameters.

```
geo/reverse_geocode.json?lat=41.83&long=-87.68
```

Comment: Yes i am trying to call twitter API bur as i have a lot of coordinates i have to automate it. Thanks for your comment, i used the method @Xiddoc suggested :)